# Spring Boot Beanのスコープであるsingletonとapplicationの違いについて

Tags: spring-boot

SpringBootのBeanのスコープで分からない事があります。
ご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

【質問】
Beanのスコープにsingletonとapplicationがあります。
このスコープの違いが分からないのですが、何が違うのでしょうか。

singleton、applicationは以下の様に記述されていましたが、
同じような事(Webアプリケーション毎に共有する事が可能？）を言っているように
見受けられるのですが、違うのでしょうか、

【singleton】
DIコンテナの起動時に、Beanのインスタンスを生成し、同一のインスタンスを共有して利用する。

【application】
サーブレットのコンテキスト単位でBeanのインスタンスを生成する。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは、はじめまして。

基本的にはSpringアプリケーション内で参照できるコンポーネントであることに違いはありません。

Singletonスコープ、の場合は同一の **ApplicationCotext** 内から参照できます。

Applicationをスコープにした場合は、**ServeltContext** の単位で参照できるコンポーネントになります。
ServletContextは複数のApplicationContextを保持している場合があります。
簡単にいえば同じシステムの中で複数のアプリケーションが動いている場合横断して参照できるスコープです。

基本的にはデフォルトで、Singletonになることから分かるように実装上の理由がなければ、Singletonを利用すればよいと思います。

ApplicationContextはSpring固有のもので、ServletContextはJavaサーブレットの一般的な概念にあたるので、混乱しないように注意しましょう。

参照URL :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819633/spring-singleton-scope-vs-application-scope/49820934
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

### 追記

Spring Boot(MVC)は下記のようにDipsatcherServletを経由して動作します。なのでこの一個のDispatcherServeltの範囲が、applicationContextで、Singletonスコープが参照できる範囲です。applicationレベルのスコープでは複数のDispatcherServletを参照できます。

粒度のレベルがJavaServletの概念と違うので、片方しか使わないなら混同するのでJavaServletの仕組みは忘れてしまう/参考にしないのもいいんじゃないかと思います。

https://yiingw.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/springmvc1.jpg?w=640

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。基本的な事でたいへん申し訳ございませんが、ServeltContextとは以下のURLの画像１にあるサーブレットコンテナと同じ範囲のイメージでしょうか。また、ApplicationCotextとは各Webアプリケーション毎と同じ範囲のイメージでしょうか。https://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/0212/09/epn14.html

Comment: 含まれる各サーブレットがアプリケーション全体と通信するためのインターフェースをサーブレットコンテキストと呼びます。コンテキスト(文脈)はJVMにつき一個です、この図は少し分かりづらいですね。モジュール単位で下記のリンク先のの図にあるサーブレットがApplicationContextの範囲になります。https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/servlet-configcontext-archi-guide-2.jpg.webp

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。ご連絡いただきました内容を確認して、私のやりたかったことがSingletonで問題ない事が分かりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 例えば、「同じシステムの中で複数のアプリケーションが動いている場合横断して参照できるスコープです。」という文章を例にとると、「システム」「アプリケーション」が具体的に何を指しているのか不明確なので説明になっていないと感じます。

Comment: こんにちは、すいません。コメントいただいて勉強になります、間違いもあることは理解しました。専門から外れてますのでご容赦ください、改善できるところはしていきたいと思います。ご指摘の件ですが、OS的なざっくりしたシステムの中に複数のアプリケーションは含まれませんか? より具体性のある文章にするとこの場合、理解を妨げないでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

簡単に:

Spring Bootをウェブアプリケーションフレームワークとして利用する場合、Java EE Servlet specに則った Servlet Container(例えばTomcat)上で動作させます。

**application**-scope は Servlet containerであるところのTomcatが管理するメモリ空間(`ServletContext`)にbeanを置きます。

**singleton**-scope は IoC container であるところのSpring自身が管理するメモリ空間(`ApplicationContext`)にbeanを置きます。

なので、 **application-scope ⊇ singleton-scope** という関係になりますが、典型的なSpring Bootアプリケーションでは `ApplicationContext` は1つだけで十分であり、いわゆるsingletonとしたいオブジェクトはwebスタックに依存しない`ApplicationContext`で管理するのが一般的かと思います。

- [Spring MVC - 1.1.1. Context Hierarchy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-context-hierarchy)

---

もう少し正確に:

質問文に記載されている各scopeに関する説明文のオリジナルは、[Spring徹底入門 Spring FrameworkによるJavaアプリケーション開発](https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798142470)という書籍の2.1.7 Beanのスコープ 節にある  「表2.4 Spring Framework で利用可能なスコープ」 です。
(web上でヒットするのはこの書籍からの引き写しと思われます)

そして、この表は 公式リファレンス [1.5. Bean Scopes 節](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes) にある「Table 3. Bean Scopes」を翻訳したものです。

この部分の後続の 「[Application Scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-application)」節で、質問文の疑問に対して直接言及されています:

> This(注: application-scope beanのこと) is somewhat similar to a Spring singleton bean but differs in two important ways: It is a singleton per ServletContext, not per Spring 'ApplicationContext' (for which there may be several in any given web application), [後略]

ここで、 "application" や "singleton" という用語は、それぞれのcontext上で認識される単位の application や singleton であり、同じ単語でも指しているものが違うことに注意してください。

例えば、`ApplicationContext` の "application" はIoC Container上のアプリケーションという単位を指していますが、scope名の `application` は Servlet Container上のアプリケーション(いわゆるwebアプリケーション)を指している、という具合です。

---

補足:

[こちらのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/68772/spring-boot-bean%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b9%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%97%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8bsingleton%e3%81%a8application%e3%81%ae%e9%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment75630_68776)

> ServeltContextとは以下のURLの画像１にあるサーブレットコンテナと同じ範囲のイメージでしょうか。また、ApplicationCotextとは各Webアプリケーション毎と同じ範囲のイメージでしょうか。([link](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/enterprise/0212/09/epn14.html))

についてですが、前述の通り、サーブレットコンテナというのはTomcatのこと、コンテキストというのが `ServletContext` のことです(contextというのは1つのアプリケーションが動作する境界付けられたメモリ空間、みたいな認識で取り敢えずは良いかと思います)。

「各Webアプリケーション毎」は、正確には `ServletContext`(図中の「コンテキスト」が該当)ですが、これも前述の通り、一般的なSpring Bootアプリケーションでは大抵の場合`ApplicationContext`も同等、と見なせるでしょう。

また、[こちらのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/68772/spring-boot-bean%e3%81%ae%e3%82%b9%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%97%e3%81%a7%e3%81%82%e3%82%8bsingleton%e3%81%a8application%e3%81%ae%e9%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment75632_68776)

> 含まれる各サーブレットがアプリケーション全体と通信するためのインターフェースをサーブレットコンテキストと呼びます。コンテキスト(文脈)はJVMにつき一個です、この図は少し分かりづらいですね。モジュール単位で下記のリンク先のの図にあるサーブレットがApplicationContextの範囲になります。([link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/servlet-configcontext-archi-guide-2.jpg.webp))

について、最初のコンテキストの説明が私には理解できませんでしたが、少なくとも「コンテキストがJVMにつき1つ」「リンク先のServletが`ApplicationContext`の範囲」というのは誤りです。

- `ServletContext` にしろ `ApplicationContext` にしろ今回登場しているものは全て同一JVM上で動作している場合で成立します。

  - 1つのTomcat上で複数のwarをデプロイするとその数だけ`ServletContext`が存在することになります。
  - 1つのSpring Bootアプリケーション上で必要に応じて`ApplicationContext`を作成できます([4.1.5. Fluent Builder API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-fluent-builder-api))。
- `ApplicationContext` は複数のServlet間で共有できます([1.1.1. Context Hierarchy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-context-hierarchy))。

[本文](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68776/2808)の記述内容についても誤認識(あるいは理解不足)があるように思われますので、個人的には、そちらの回答はむしろ理解の妨げになるように感じます。